# Default threshold for moving an object from Young generation to Old Generation

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In java what is default threshold for young generation object to move to old generation. I mean how many GC an object need to survive so that it can be moved to old or tenured generation area of heap.

Comment: This may help: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/useful-jvm-flags-part-5-young-generation-garbage-collection/

Comment: look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The option is called `-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold`.

Docs say, the default value is 15 for [G1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html) and parallel collector and is 4 for CMS ([source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)).